# How to get the next 10,000 data from google analytics api using php?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

Good day,

Is there a way to get the next 10,000 data from google analytics API?
I would want to get the next set of data after getting the first 10,000. Is there a way to accomplish that? I am using google analytics api php client libraries.

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
 $analytics = initializeAnalytics();     
 $response = getReport($analytics);  
 printResults($response);

function initializeAnalytics()
{
    $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . 'MyFileDirectory';
    // Create and configure a new client object.
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
    $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
    $client-
>setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
    $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);
    return $analytics;
 }

function getReport($analytics) {
    // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
    $VIEW_ID = "MyViewId";

    // Create the DateRange object.
    $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
    $dateRange->setStartDate("2017-04-01");
    $dateRange->setEndDate("2017-06-19");

    // Create the Metrics object.
    $totalEvents = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
    $totalEvents->setExpression("ga:totalEvents");
    $totalEvents->setAlias("totalEvents");

    //Create the Dimensions object.
    $clientId = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $clientId->setName("ga:dimension4");
    $sessionId = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $sessionId->setName("ga:dimension5");
    $eventLabel = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $eventLabel->setName("ga:eventLabel");
    $timestamp = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $timestamp->setName("ga:dimension3");

    // Create the ReportRequest object.
    $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
    $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
    //set number of rows
    $request->setPageSize(10000);
    $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
    $request->setMetrics(array($totalEvents));
    $request->setDimensions(array($clientId,$sessionId,$eventLabel, 
    $timestamp));   
    $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
    $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
    return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/pagination?

Comment: @JordiNebot Thank you for the suggestion. I will try to put this on my code. I hope this is the answer.

Comment: @JordiNebot I tried it and the error is "Call to a member function getNextPageToken() on null"

Comment: @ben your going to have to do a var dump of the response and figure out where nextpagetoken is and use that.    Analyics v4 is different then the other APIs the standard pagination methods are not going to work.   I had to re-write it myself for C#

Comment: @DaImTo did you use PHP before? Let me try what you suggested. Have you successfully tried it on C#?

Comment: @ben yes i have used PHP before.   I have a sample project of it working in C# https://github.com/LindaLawton/GoogleAnalytics-v4   I have also contacted the Google analytics API team and suggested they put up some sample code for this.   I have offered my assistance but it may be a while before we get it written, approved and uploaded.      If your interested in reading what the issue is with it and the standard pagination solutions you can read my write up in the .net client library https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/818

Comment: @DaImTo, Thank you for your inputs. I am using PHP now and I really want  to accomplish this but only few inputs or samples were there. Only few support on PHP. Have you tested pagination on PHP? Will be viewing your write up in a few.

Comment: No i haven't bothered doing it in any language other then C# at this time.   If you check the Github issue thread you are probably going to have similar issues in the PHP client library.

Comment: @DaImTo, Thank you, I will try doing it on C# and follow your samples. Looking forward to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you cant figure it out in PHP Ping me i will give it a shot.

Comment: @DaImTo To be honest, I am stuck on this part for I think a month now. I am new to Analytics API but I doing my best to understand the api references. It is very complex for me. I would really appreciate it if you could assist me on this or give some sample code so that I can base it there. Thank you so much

Comment: it will have to wait until the morning.  I will just turn it into a tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to get the first 10 pages of data.   I limited it to 10 to prevent it from eating my quota.  If you remove that it will continue to chug away getting all the rows and eating up your quota.

NOTE: This is only going to work if you have a single report.  If you have more then one report then you are going to have to do some fancy stuff to apply the correct pageToken to each report and remove the reports which are complete.   At this time there is no report Id or way of matching up what you sent to the report that is returned other than its place in the reports array.

```
$service = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client); 

// Create the DateRange object.
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate("2016-01-01");
$dateRange->setEndDate("2017-06-30");

// Create the Metrics object.
$sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
$sessions->setAlias("sessions");

//Create the Dimensions object.
$date = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$date->setName("ga:date");
$pagePath = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$pagePath->setName("ga:pagePath");

// Create the ReportRequest object.
$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setViewId("81692014");
$request->setPageSize("10000");  
$request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
$request->setDimensions(array($date,$pagePath));
$request->setMetrics(array($sessions));
$request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

$body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
$body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
$data =  $service->reports->batchGet( $body );


// Remove count if you really want everything.
$cnt = 0; 
while ($data->reports[0]->nextPageToken > 0 && $cnt < 10) {
    // There are more rows for this report.
    $body->reportRequests[0]->setPageToken($data->reports[0]->nextPageToken);
    $data =  $service->reports->batchGet( $body );
    $cnt++;
    }
```

I put a tutorial up on it [Google Analytics V4 pagination](http://www.daimto.com/google-analytics-v4-pagination/)  and the full code i used can be found on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/1bdf5d6259c161c5bff35db0c01710da) note this code was ripped from my sample project.

Comment: @DalmTo, thank you for the tutorial. It was really a very big help. It works now. I got the right data and inserted those data on my database.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer.   You will also get points when you accept welcome to stack overflow