# google analytics api suddenly stopped returning data after working for many months

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

My analytics api stopped returning rows the other day.  I see the data in the analytics api.  What could cause this?  Is it a quota issue?  Is there some messages the api returns that could tell me what is going on?

It worked flawlessly prior to this.  I'm not seeing any visible errors when I manually run the script.  I am using composer to include the SDK, and it's up to date.  I do appear to be able to initialize my Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client)

When I make the report request, I just don't get any rows or any indication as to why I am no longer getting any rows returned.

My code is based on the accepted answer here [How to get the next 10,000 data from google analytics api using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191768/how-to-get-the-next-10-000-data-from-google-analytics-api-using-php)

I apparently am still getting data but the while loop never fires now.  I have views where the next page token value is blank, and at least 1 where it is > 10000.

Any help on steps to take to trouble shoot this would be greatly appreciated.  Issue started on 9.19

```
$data = $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
    
$cnt = 0; 
while ($data->reports[0]->nextPageToken > 0 && $cnt < 10) {
    // There are more rows for this report.
    $body->reportRequests[0]->setPageToken($data->reports[0]->nextPageToken);
    $pagedata = $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );           
    $this->processResults($mysqli, $pagedata, $auth);            
}
```

Comment: Seems like the nextPageToken api code may have changed on the day my issue started, so the way I was paginating results to get more than 10000 rows doesn't work any more.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  I am not aware of any braking changes to the Google Analytics api.

Comment: Have you considered that it could be related to todays outages?  https://status.cloud.google.com/   When did it start happening?

Comment: My code is basically the same and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191768/how-to-get-the-next-10-000-data-from-google-analytics-api-using-php

Comment: We need your code in your question.  Not a link to code you are following which could be changed at anytime.  Why not post a question over there im wondering if this question is in fact a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking if nextPageToken is a number fixed my issue.

```
    if(is_numeric($data->reports[0]->nextPageToken)){
        //nextPageToken is a number
        $cnt = 0; 
        
        while ($data->reports[0]->nextPageToken > 0 && $cnt < 5) {                            
            $body->reportRequests[0]->setPageToken($data->reports[0]->nextPageToken);
            $data = $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
            $this->processResults($mysqli, $data, $auth);
            $cnt++;
        }       
        
    }else{
        //nextPageToken IS NOT A NUMBER
        $data = $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
        $this->processResults($mysqli, $data, $auth);
    }
```

Comment: Does anybody have a better way to loop thru more than 10,000 GA records or is this still acceptable?